# Is parkour on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We just got our first question on parkour. Is the practice on topic? I'm not aware of any competitions in parkour which would have it failing one of my more basic "is it a sport" criteria. However, it's something of an athletic activity, should it be on topic?

Comment: Here an interesting article named "parkour is not a sport" - http://www.flipyeahparkour.com/2012/01/parkour-is-not-a-sport/

Answer (score 3):

It is in fact a sport. If your definition requires it to be competitive, there was in fact [official competitions](http://wfpf.com/history-parkour-0) for it.

> In October of 2007, The RED BULL ART OF MOTION in Vienna was the first major competition around Parkour and Freerunning held anywhere in the world. First place was taken by WFPF/Airborn athlete Ryan Doyle, with WFPF /Tempest athletes, Victor Lopez and Gabe Nunez tying for second, and WFPF/Air Wipp athlete Marcus Gustavsson taking third.

Comment: it's a minimum bar, but it's not the only one (for instance, I wouldn't consider cross fit to be a sport necessarily)

Comment: so what are the requirements to consider it a sport exactly?

Comment: Is your question aimed toward a competitive aspect of parkour? If so, then sure...it would be on-topic here and Fitness SE. For example, running for general fitness is better suited for Fitness SE...but running for 5Ks, triathlons, etc. would be well suited in both places.

Comment: @Ephraim See [this](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/162/527)... In addition, there are other meta topics about the considerations of sport.

Comment: my question is aimed towards the technique. The question is, would a question about the technique of running a 5k be on topic here?

Comment: Yes. Are there specific competitions that solely focus on doing kongs?

Comment: Yes, technique questions are on topic.

Comment: @Sancho technique questions in terms of activities deemed to be on-topic on Fitness SE isn't necessarily on-topic on Sports SE unless said activity is deemed on-topic on Sports SE

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkour),

> Parkour is a training discipline that developed out of military
>   obstacle course training.
>
> Practitioners aim to move from one place to another, negotiating the
>   obstacles in between. The discipline uses no equipment and is
>   non-competitive.

Considering it's a training discipline and non-competitive, I would lean toward having this on [Fitness SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=parkour).

Comment: pretty sure that's where I stand as well, shall we make sure it's on topic on fitness? Looks like it is http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parkour

Comment: @waxeagle I'm feeling confident http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4875/how-to-train-for-parkour-as-middle-aged-beginner